# How can I add Taglib in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, taglib

I want to make my `jsp` page more dynamic,so I need used `taglib`.

The questions I want to ask is that

1) Where I can **download** taglib jars?

2) How can I **configure** it in my project?

Answer (score -1):

**To Download the taglibs:**

Use Maven central repo:

http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/

http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/taglibs/standard/

**how to package and use custom taglib (maven jar project)**

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643495/how-to-add-tld-and-tag-lib-files-into-a-mavens-jar-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118772/how-to-use-taglibs-jstl-core-with-jar-in-web-inf-folder)

[How to use taglibs JSTL/core with JAR in WEB-INF folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118772/how-to-use-taglibs-jstl-core-with-jar-in-web-inf-folder)

use google....

Answer (score -1):

Most probably already late.

I have configured taglibs via pom file using:
https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-taglibs/6.0.2/jar

and then on the jsp page at the very top before html tags:
<%@ taglib prefix="security" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>

later you can use <security:... />

for instance <security:authentication property="principal.username" />